# multi-class weighted loss function in pytorch

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am training a unet based model for multi-class segmentation task on pytorch framework. Optimizing the model with following loss function,

```
class MulticlassJaccardLoss(_Loss):
"""Implementation of Jaccard loss for multiclass (semantic) image segmentation task
"""
__name__ = 'mc_jaccard_loss'
def __init__(self, classes: List[int] = None, from_logits=True, weight=None, reduction='elementwise_mean'):
    super(MulticlassJaccardLoss, self).__init__(reduction=reduction)
    self.classes = classes
    self.from_logits = from_logits
    self.weight = weight

def forward(self, y_pred: Tensor, y_true: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    """
    :param y_pred: NxCxHxW
    :param y_true: NxHxW
    :return: scalar
    """
    if self.from_logits:
        y_pred = y_pred.softmax(dim=1)

    n_classes = y_pred.size(1)
    smooth = 1e-3

    if self.classes is None:
        classes = range(n_classes)
    else:
        classes = self.classes
        n_classes = len(classes)

    loss = torch.zeros(n_classes, dtype=torch.float, device=y_pred.device)

    if self.weight is None:
        weights = [1] * n_classes
    else:
        weights = self.weight

    for class_index, weight in zip(classes, weights):

        jaccard_target = (y_true == class_index).float()
        jaccard_output = y_pred[:, class_index, ...]

        num_preds = jaccard_target.long().sum()

        if num_preds == 0:
            loss[class_index-1] = 0 #custom
        else:
            iou = soft_jaccard_score(jaccard_output, jaccard_target, from_logits=False, smooth=smooth)
            loss[class_index-1] = (1.0 - iou) * weight #custom

    if self.reduction == 'elementwise_mean':
        return loss.mean()

    if self.reduction == 'sum':
        return loss.sum()

    return loss
```

I am calculating loss for only two classes (class 1 and 2 and not for the background).

```
MulticlassJaccardLoss(weight=[0.5,10], classes=[1,2], from_logits=False)
```

When I train the model, it trains for first few iterations and I get the following error,

```
element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

What is the mistake in the code?

Thanks!

Comment: `weight` is not a `Tensor`, maybe that's the problem? What is the exact line where the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting:

```
torch.zeros(..., requires_grad=True)
```

I believe requires_grad=False is the default for torch.zeros, so this may help here.